# Sandbox - Mappers and reducers determined

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have taken cloud computing and created a project in Mapreduce for weather analysis. For this purpose, I installed the below software in my laptop.

- Oracle Virtualbox
- HortonWorks sandbox

I selected Redhat Linux and allocated 2 GB as the main memory. I used the hadoop image from sandbox site and loaded it using virtualbox. If my understanding is correct, the 2 GB is allocated from my system and the MapReduce job is done in my local machine itself. Am I correct in this point?

I created my MapReduce program and ran it in sandbox. It worked fine and I got the desired output.

- For my job, the job tracker showed that 8 mappers were used and for reduce one reducer was used. So the 8 mappers were basically 8 splits of my 2 GB main memory which were used as mappers for processing the data.

If the above statement is correct, why do I see only one reducer being used?

If the mappers are from sandbox, do they have servers like Amazon's EMR?

Comment: I recommend you read "HBase: The Definitive Guide". It will answer your questions.

Comment: @zsxwing : He's nowhere talking about HBase. Do you mean Hadoop Definitive Guide?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. yes, i mean "Hadoop: the Definitive Guide". For hadoop newbies, I highly recommend this book.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but I didn't quite get what exactly you are trying to ask. You question looks like a post's title more than a question.

Mappers and Reducers are something which are the components of `MapReduce framework`. Hortonworks is just one of the vendors who provide custom Hadoop distributions. There are certain differences among these different flavors of Hadoop, but the criteria of Mapper and Reducer creation is same everywhere.

> If my understanding is correct, the 2 GB is allocated from my system
>   and the MapReduce job is done in my local machine itself. Am I correct
>   in this point?

First of all recommended memory is `4GB`.

Yes, it'll be allocated from the machine where virtualbox is running. Where else would you get resources from when virtualbox is running on "this" machine? And what does allocated memory have to do with where MR jobs are running?When you are using the sandbox, they'll run in the sandbox.

> For my job, the job tracker showed that 8 mappers were used and for
>   reduce one reducer was used. So the 8 mappers were basically 8 splits
>   of my 2 GB main memory which were used as mappers for processing the
>   data.

8 mappers were 8 instances of your Mapper code which were processing 8 splits of your input data and `NOT` 8 splits of memory, or anything else.

```
If the mappers are from sandbox, do they have servers like Amazon's EMR?
```

This is a total bouncer for me. Please rephrase it.

Comment: I wanted to know if my code is running in Sandbox's server or my own local machine itself. Basically, my question was, if it had been my machine itself, only one machine was used rather than multiple machines as supposed to be for a mapreduce job. I am pretty new to this concept and kindly let me know if you are not clear with my question.

Comment: Although MR was designed to be used in a distributed environment, it doesn't stop us from running jobs on a single machine. If you are on a single multicore machine, it is very much possible that more than one mappers are running in parallel, based on the availability of CPU slots...Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Identity mapper is used when you want to read the data and process as it is without any change.